# Swing: Load a XML file content into JLabels

Tags: java, xml, swing, load

I'm developing a Java Swing Application, and I have a Main Frame, and many other frames that can be opened therethrough. 
One option that can be performed is to **Load a File (XML)** through the main window and then, when I open a second window, that window will **present the data that stored on that file**, in the respective fields.

I already can Load the File through the main window, but how can present that information in another window?

I've used `StAX` to get the content of the XML File, and the `Swing Worker` to load the file. I need to fill two `jTables` with some of the content, and some `JLabels` with values that are also stored in the file.

Comment: Please give some examples. Did you do that with DOM/SAX? Did you store your data in another class. How many JLabels do you use? When to print out information?, ...

Comment: My big doubt is how to access the file content from another frame. I think that some detailed information is not necessary. But see if what I edit is enough.

Comment: You should load the XML file content into another class and reference this class to the new frame. So you can access data over different classes and worker.

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement an Adapter (ie a DataModel) following to your requirement for your JTable.

I suggest you to read the Java documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).

Personnaly, I recommend JAXB to parse your xml data because it can build a model. Your architecture should be based on the model your xml file represents. Then your Adapter will be a transition to the AbstractDataModel class and your model.